# How to log the capistrano deployment result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

How can I log the capistrano deployment result?

I have to log the capistrano deployment result so that if there is any problem while deploying the code on multiple servers I can come to know by viewing the log file.

Can any one suggest how to do this?

Does capistrano log the deployment result?

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem: https://github.com/jnewland/capistrano-log_with_awesome

Comment: Thanks Martin. I will go through this gem once. Once again thanks for suggesting this.